# Converting output to include discounts when applicable

Tags: java

Here's the code I have so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Random;

public class TicketInfo
{
   static final double STUDENT_DISCOUNT = .80;
   static final double FACULTY_STAFF_DISCOUNT = .20;
   /**
    *Prints date, time, section, row, seat, 
    *price, cost, final cost with discount.
    *
    *@param args Command line arguements (not used).
    */
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
      DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("$#,##0.00");
      DecimalFormat form = new DecimalFormat("###");
      String ticketCode = "";
      String event = "";
      String date = "";
      String time = "";
      String section = "";
      String row = "";
      String seat = "";
      String price = "";
      String type = "";
      String cost = "";
      int section1, row1, seat1;
      double price1, cost1;
      Random generator = new Random();
      int random;

  System.out.print("Enter your ticket code: ");
  ticketCode = userInput.nextLine();
  System.out.println();

  //Trims any extra white spaces.
  ticketCode = ticketCode.trim();


  if (ticketCode.length() > 27)
  {
  //Breaks down the ticket code into parts
     type = ticketCode.substring(0, 3);

     date = ticketCode.substring(14, 16) + "/" 
        + ticketCode.substring(16, 18) 
        + "/" + ticketCode.substring(18, 22);  

     time = ticketCode.substring(22, 24) 
        + ":" 
        + ticketCode.substring(24, 26);

     section = ticketCode.substring(4, 5);
     row = ticketCode.substring(5, 7);
     seat = ticketCode.substring(8, 9);
     price = ticketCode.substring(9, 12); 
     event = ticketCode.substring(26, ticketCode.length());
     cost = ticketCode.substring(10, 14);

  //Converts Doubles or Integers in a string into its numeric value.
     section1 = Integer.parseInt(section);
     row1 = Integer.parseInt(row);
     seat1 = Integer.parseInt(seat);
     price1 = Double.parseDouble(price);
     cost1 = Double.parseDouble(cost);

  //Calculate cost based on ticket type

     random = generator.nextInt(999999) + 1;

   // Print results
     System.out.println("Event: " + event + "   Date: " 
        + date + "   Time: " + time);

     System.out.println("Section: " + form.format(section1) + "   Row: " 
        + form.format(row1) + "   Seat: " + form.format(seat1)); 

     System.out.println("Price: " + fmt.format(price1) + "   Ticket Type: " 
        + type + "   Cost: " + fmt.format(price1)); 

     System.out.println("Raffle Number: " + random);

  }
  else 
  {

     System.out.println("Invalid Ticket Code.");
     System.out.println("Ticket code must have at least 27 characters.");
  }
```

}

}

```
Output as of now: 

Enter your ticket code: STU01280712500091920151430Auburn vs LSU

Event: Auburn vs LSU   Date: 09/19/2015   Time: 14:30
Section: 1   Row: 28   Seat: 7
Price: $125.00   Ticket Type: STU   Cost: $125.00
Raffle Number: 939894
```

I need to make the cost output have discount included. For example, STU type = 80% discount, and F/S type = 20% and REG = no discount.
Goal is to make the cost include the 80% discount for STU ticket type      which would make the cost 25.00 for student and 100.00 for faculty with a 20% discount. I think my problem is concerned with constants but I'm not sure since I'm a beginner.

Comment: Your problem is "not with constants" but that you're never actually using the constants anywhere. The discounts in the constants will not be magically applied, but rather you will have to write code that uses them for them to apply. I suggest you give that a try first *before* coming here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do an "if" condition with the type (LSU, STU, REG)

```
    price1 = Double.parseDouble(price);
    if(type.equals("STU")){
          price1 = price1 * STUDENT_DISCOUNT;
    }
    else if(type.equals("LSU")){
          price1 = price1 * FACULTY_STAFF_DISCOUNT;
    }
```